# SQL Server 2005 select query not retrieving complete text from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Maybe this would be very simple, but I have no idea why this is happening.

To put in simple way, I have inserted a row into a database table which contains a `ntext` column called `content`. String value which got in to this column `content` has a text length of 6889 characters. However when I do a basic select query based on id, it do retrieve the row - but not the complete text from the column `Content`. All I see in SQL Server Management Studio for this column when I do a select query is the text with characters 43679.

There is no issue with data being inserted and I could see all the text being displayed in front end application. The issue is only when I do a select query, and copy the text to notepad, I do see fewer characters. Anything with respect to SQL Server settings/paging/statistics? Appreciate if anyone could help me out with this.

thanks,
KK

Answer (score 3):

I encountered [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298174/ms-sql-server-2008r2-how-to-retrieve-the-content-of-a-large-text-column/22298416?noredirect=1#comment33888264_22298416), and I found that SSMS is unable to fully retrieve column that is longer than 43680 (in output to Grid mode).

So the work around is output it as XML (unlimited length):

```
SELECT convert(xml,'<xml><![CDATA[' + cast([your column] as varchar(max)) + ']]></xml>')
```

Then do a quick search and replace (`&lt;` to `<` , `&gt;` to `>` ) . You can now copy the result to Notepad++ to view all the content.

Answer (score 1):

SSMS returns a maximum number of characters to the grid or text window of every text based column: SSMS menu: options: Query results node : SQL node : Results to grid / Results to text

I'm sure there is a good reason for this: probably SSMS would fall over even more regularly than it does now.

Hope this helps... no such thing as a silly question